# Try to Save Session phone variable but when moving to page the Session is empty

Tags: javascript, php

I am new in php and I am try to Practince and under stand Session
I have 3 files. api.php, index.php and updatePassword.php

I want to update password per phone number of user. (for practice)

I want to send from index.php the phone number to api.php check if password is "Gasolina123" I want to update password of the user

from some reason the Session is deleted altough I save it in

attaching relavent code:

index.php javascript:

```
<script>
function submitForm() {
    // Get form data
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("login-form"));
    var phoneNumber = document.getElementsByName("phone")[0].value;
    var passwordFromUser = formData.get("passwordFromUser"); // Retrieve password

    // Send AJAX request to api.php with the action set to 'login'
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "api.php", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            // Handle the response
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            sessionStorage.setItem('phone', phoneNumber);
            if (response.status === "update_password") {
                // Redirect to update password page
                window.location.href = "update-password.php";
            } else if (response.status === "ok") {
                // Set phone number in session storage
                // Redirect to home page
                window.location.href = "homePage.php";
            } else if (response.error) {
                // Display error message returned from the server
                alert("שגיאה: " + response.error);
            } else {
                // Unexpected response, display generic error message
                alert("שגיאה - תגובה לא צפוייה");
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        } else {
            // Display error message if request fails
            alert("Error: Unable to process request. Status code: " + xhr.status);
        }
    }
};

// Set the 'action' parameter to 'login'
formData.append("action", "login");

// Send form data as the request body
xhr.send(formData);
}
</script>
```

this is api.php:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Start the session
// Include the Database class
include_once 'Database.php'; 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

// Create a new Database object
$db = new Database();

// Check if phone number is set in the form data
if(isset($_POST['phone'])) {
    $_SESSION['phone'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']); // Set phone number in session
}

// Check if phone number is set in the form data
if(isset($_POST['phoneNumber'])) {
    $_SESSION['phone'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['phoneNumber']); // Set phone number in 
}


// Check if an action is specified
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
    case 'login':
        // Handle login action
        if(isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['passwordFromUser'])) {
            $phone = $_POST['phone'];
            $password = md5(md5($_POST['passwordFromUser'])); // Hash the password
            
            // Check if phone exists in the database
            if ($db->phoneExists($phone)) {
                // Retrieve hashed password from the database
                $stored_password = $db->getPassword($phone);

                // Verify the entered password against the hashed password
                if ($password == $stored_password) {
                    // Password is correct
                    // Check if the password needs to be updated
                    $stored_password_hash = md5(md5('Gasolina123'));
                    if ($password == $stored_password_hash) {
                        // Password update is required
                        echo json_encode(['status' => 'update_password']);
                    } else {
                        // Successful login
                        echo json_encode(['status' => 'ok']);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Password is incorrect
                    echo json_encode(['error'=> 'סיסמא לא נכונה']);
                }
            } else {
                // Phone number not found in the database
                echo json_encode(['error'=> 'הטלפון לא נמצא במאגר']);
            }
        } else {
            // Missing phone or password parameters
            echo json_encode(['error' => 'חסרים פרמטרים']);
        }
        break;
```

and this is the update password.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // Start the session
print_r($_SESSION);

if(isset($_SESSION['phone'])) {
    //echo "Phone number is set: ".$_SESSION['phone'];
    $phone = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['phone']); // Retrieve phone number from session
} else {
    echo "Phone number is not set in session";
    // Redirect to login page if phone number is not set in session
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit; // Stop executing the script
}
?>
```

Comment: Please don't store passwords using the [obsolete, insecure md5 algorithm](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) - that is a security risk. Learn about PHP's built-in, up-to-date, secure [password hashing and verification functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead. See also [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords). I wonder if you have been following an old and/or poor-quality tutorial which suggested that you use this approach.

Comment: Your usage of `htmlspecialchars()` is inappropriate and potentially problematic. `htmlspecialchars()` is an _output_ filter, only to be used _specifically_ when _outputting_ data into a HTML document. It is designed only to help protect against XSS. It should not be used at any other time, such as when receiving input data -in the worst case it can change or corrupt your data unnecessarily in that situation. It also has nothing to do with preventing SQL injection. See [when to use htmlspecialchars() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882307/when-to-use-htmlspecialchars-function)

Comment: **Warning**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. It is not generally a suitable topic for an inexperienced or beginner programmer. Any [modern development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. I recommend focusing your time on learning PHP and adding genuine value to your application with new features, not something you can re-use a (reliable, well-made) product for.